# JWT decode, AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'

Tags: python, web, jwt

I've recently tried my hand at some web page development and I am trying to use JSON web tokens. I'm using the endpoint below as a very basic login. Unfortunately, I am getting the following error:

`AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'`

I spoke to my professor at my University and they could not find out why it was behaving like this. Any help is appreciated!

Thanks

**Login endpoint:**

```
@app.route("/api/v1.0/login", methods=["GET"])
def login():
    auth = request.authorization
    if auth and auth.password == 'password':
        token = jwt.encode({
            'user': auth.username,
            'exp': datetime.datetime.utcnow() + datetime.timedelta(minutes=30)
        }, app.config['SECRET_KEY'])
        return jsonify( { 'token': token.decode('UTF-8') } )
    return make_response('Could not verify', 401, {
        'WWW-Authenticate': 'Basic realm = "Login required"'
    })
```

**Imports **

```
from flask import Flask, make_response, jsonify, request
from bson import ObjectId
from pymongo import MongoClient
import uuid, random
import jwt
import datetime
from functools import wraps
```

I have looked at similar questions on stackover flow but they only seem to talk about the positioning of 'decode' and i think mine is in the right place